# Can I have a compile time bound check for std::array if the index is known to the compiler and normal behaviour otherwise?

Tags: c++, arrays

As a simple example consider the following class:

```
template <int N>
class A {
private:
  std::array<double, N> m_vs = {};
public:
  int size() {return N;}
  void set_value(double d, int n=0) {m_vs[n] = d;}
  double get_value(int n=0) {return m_vs[n];}
}
```

Let's say that we have `a = A<10>()`.

I would like the compiler to throw an error if I type `a.set_value(1, 20)` since it is known that this will be out of bounds, but not throw any error if I write `a.set_value(1, i)` since `i` could be valid.

Is it possible to get such behaviour?

Comment: *"since `i` could be valid...."* So how could the compiler make such a runtime decision? Function parameter are not `constexpr`.

Comment: @user12002570 the compiler can know that 20 is out of bounds but has no clue if `i` is valid or not. So I want to have an error in the former case but not in the latter.

Comment: There is no difference between the passed arguments `20` and `i` here when you called the function(lvalue/rvalue etc not counting here ). They're the same in this context of calling. Basically, both bound to a function parameter and the function parameter `n` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: You can make template non-type parameter which are `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get a compile time check for your runtime value. You can get

- Compiletime checks for your `constexpr` values
- Runtime checks for runtime values

Example:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
class A {
private:
    std::array<double, N> m_vs = {};

public:
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return N; }

    // use these with runtime `n`s:
    double get_value(std::size_t n) {
        if (n >= N) throw std::out_of_range("get_value: n >= N");
        return m_vs[n];
    }

    void set_value(double d, std::size_t n) {
        if (n >= N) throw std::out_of_range("set_value: n >= N");
        m_vs[n] = d;
    }

    // use these with `n`s known at compile time:
    template <std::size_t n = 0>
    double get_value() {
        static_assert(n < N, "n < N failed");
        return m_vs[n];
    }

    template <std::size_t n = 0>
    void set_value(double d) {
        static_assert(n < N, "n < N failed");
        m_vs[n] = d;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main() {
    A<10> a;

    a.set_value(3.141);      // n == 0, all's well (if N > 0, else compile time error)
    a.set_value<10>(3.141);  // compile time time error, 10 is out-of-bounds
    a.set_value(3.141, 10);  // runtime access out-of-bounds, throws exception
}
```

Comment: That was relatively straightforward after all. Thanks! :)

Comment: `std::integral_constant` and udl might be an alternative syntax: `a.set_value(3.141, 10_c)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, absolutely!